# How to use JSON response from InvokeHTTP to create a header for another InvokeHTTP?

Tags: apache-nifi

The following flow takes a username/password combination and authenticates against an API via InvokeHTTP:

[image]

The result of InvokeHTTP is an authentication token:

[image]

I want to use this token in any preceding API calls. What flow do I need to provide the auth token as an authorization header for InvokeHTTP? The header has to look like this:

```
Authorization: Token ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [`EvaluateJsonPath`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) processor to extract a JSON value using the JsonPath expression `$.token` and *Destination* `flowfile-attribute`, which will place it in an attribute. So using a dynamic property named *Authorization* with the value `$.token` will result in `InvokeHTTP` sending a header with the value `Authorization: abcdef....`. In order to format the header correctly, you'll want to use an `UpdateAttribute` processor between `EvaluateJsonPath` and `InvokeHTTP` to update the attribute value using the Expression Language expression `Token ${Authorization}` to prepend the literal string.